# How to make every other row a column using row below as the value in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
  df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'type': {4: 'Second Product',
  5: 'table',
  6: 'First Product',
  7: 'chair',
  8: 'Second Product',
  9: 'desk',
  10: 'First Product',
  11: 'chair'},
 'id': {4: 'cust1',
  5: 'cust1',
  6: 'cust1',
  7: 'cust1',
  8: 'cust2',
  9: 'cust2',
  10: 'cust2',
  11: 'cust2'}})
```

But I need the 'type' column broken out into column, value.  So the column names would be 'Second Product', and 'First Product', but the values would be the row below those. Like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'cust': {4:'cust1', 5:'cust2' },'Second Product': {4: 'table',
  5: 'desk'},
 'First Product': {4: 'chair',
  5: 'chair'}})
```

the other catch is, there could be more than just first and second products, and I want to get all the columns and fill blanks or nans where they don't exist.  So if there is one customer who has a 'Third Product'  I need that to be a column and where others don't have a third product value, fill that as blank or nans.

I have tried transposing, stacking, unstacking and setting indexes etc...  and I'm just stuck as to how to go about this.

Edit: I am not worried about the index being reset, so it doesn't need to match my example exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Code

```
# check if value is the header/column name
m = df['type'].str.endswith('Product')

# mask and forward fill to associate
# column name with each value below it
df['cols'] = df['type'].mask(~m).ffill()

# pivot to reshape to wide format
result = df[~m].pivot(index='id', columns='cols', values='type')
```

#### Result

```
cols  First Product Second Product
id                                
cust1         chair          table
cust2         chair           desk
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to join the dataframe with a shift of it, and pivot the result:

```
temp = df.join(df.shift(), rsuffix='_2').rename_axis(index='ix').reset_index()
temp = temp.drop(columns=['id_2'])[temp.index % 2 == 1].set_index('ix')
result = temp.pivot('id', 'type_2', 'type').rename_axis(
    index='cust', columns=None).reset_index()
```

It gives:

```
    cust First Product Second Product
0  cust1         chair          table
1  cust2         chair           desk
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) and [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension), you could do something like:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
  'type': { 4: 'Second Product', 5: 'table', 6: 'First Product', 7: 'chair',
            8: 'Second Product', 9: 'desk', 10: 'First Product', 11: 'chair' },
  'id': { 4: 'cust1', 5: 'cust1', 6: 'cust1', 7: 'cust1',
          8: 'cust2', 9: 'cust2', 10: 'cust2', 11: 'cust2' }
})

itpZip = list(zip(df['id'][::2], df['type'][::2], [*df['type'][1::2], None]))
getProdTypes = lambda c: set(ctp[1] for ctp in itpZip if c==ctp[0])
custProdTypes = {ci: getProdTypes(ci) for ci in set(df['id'][::2])}
df = pd.DataFrame([{
    'cust': ci, **{ti:', '.join(
        p for c,t,p in itpZip if c==ci and t==ti
      ) for ti in getProdTypes(ci)}
} for ci in set(df['id'][::2])])
```

[[view stages and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skRUK.png)]